# angular.element() cannot find DOM element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table of users that is populated dynamically from a Firebase database:

```
<table id="users">
    <thead>
       ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
          <td data-user-id="{{user.$id}}">{{user.$id}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
function loadUsers($scope, DatabaseFactory) {
    DatabaseFactory.users.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var users = snapshot.val();

        for(var id in users) {
            var user = users[id];

            // Find cell with user ID
            var element = angular.element('#users tr td[data-user-id="' + user.id + '"]'); // 1
            console.log(element); // 2
        }
    });
};
```

In `loadUsers()`, I'm trying to find a cell which contains a particular user ID. The log statement above returns an array with length 0. Why does this happen? When I try the statements 1 and 2 in the Chrome console, it works fine.

Comment: Show your DOM structure

Comment: Do you use jQuery in the project? Try `angular.element().find('#users tr td[data-user-id="' + user.id + '"]')`

Comment: you have to show more of your code. one possible reason for it not working in code and working in console is that element is not yet present in DOM when you execute the lines.

Comment: Added DOM structure. jQuery is not being used in the project

Comment: soo... where do you assign $scope.users ?

Comment: Why are you trying to find the elements here?  What do you plan to do with the elements?  You can't find the elements because angular hasn't had a chance to render the view before you go looking for the elements.  This is a good example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  It's generally not necessary to manipulate the DOM directly in angular in most cases, so perhaps if you explain what you are trying to accomplish, rather than the failed attempt, an angular way of accomplishing your desired result can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was turning `loadUsers()` into a directive. It is called after generating the DOM elements with `ngRepeat`.

HTML:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users" load-users>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['firebase'])
    .directive('loadUsers', loadUsers);


function loadUsers($scope, DatabaseFactory) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
           ...
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your  loop inside `viewContentLoaded` event.Its look like things are asycnhronous.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    for (var id in users) {
        var user = users[id];

        // Find cell with user ID
        var element = angular.element('#users tr td[data-user-id="' + user.id + '"]'); // 1
        console.log(element); // 2
    }
});
```

Comment: @user2181948 where is the `$scope.users`?